# How to set CSP (Content-Security-Policy) in .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, content-security-policy

If i set the CSP, my Website won't load. I am trying to avoid unsafe-inline/-eval
I use the following file structure

- .htaccess
- index.php
- markup.html
- scripts/main.js
- scripts/jquery.js
- styles/style.css
- and some other images and text files for content

I just get a white page, nevertheless if I open the source code in the browser, it is loaded but misses some of it.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    # Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' /scripts; frame-src https:;"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
</IfModule>
```

I tried in to use different codes in .htaccess like:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self' '/scripts/main.js' '/scripts/jquery.js'; frame-src https:;"
```

and

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' /scripts; frame-src https:;"
```

for the second code I set in HTML:

```
<script src="scripts/main.js" nonce="<random-nonce>"></script>
```

and in PHP

```
 $html= file_get_contents("markup.html");
 $html = str_replace("<random-nonce>", $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'], $html);
 print $html;
```

I am trying since 5 hours without success :/ It only works if I comment out the CSP in .htaccess with a #, bit of course then without CSP!

Comment: The easiest way would be to open the browser console first, which should tell you exactly which rule has failed the CSP

Comment: Thanks for your hint.
It seems, that I have to use the unsafe tag:
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src https:;"